# Generating PDF sheets from an Excel sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel

I populate an Excel spread sheet then generate A4 size sheets which has info on 2 sheets the 2 sheet has 1 line of name signature and date. I want to move that line onto the first sheet permanently. How can I do that please?

Comment: It sounds like you want to adjust your print options to "fit sheet on one page" (click on the no scaling to see the other choices). I cannot say for certainty if it works for printing to pdf.